# Can anyone show me how the definite integral is derived in the solution?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, charge

[image]

This example is from  4th edition, David J. Griffiths.
I don't understand how the definite integral is calculated. Can anyone show me?

Comment: Please note on this site we very strongly discourage using images of mathematics (or text).  For mathematics please use [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: "*I don't understand how the definite integral is calculated*" The integral is simply applying the definition of Coulomb's law, which was presented earlier in the book. What exactly are you unclear about? Please clarify.

Answer (score 2):

It's by inspection.  That is, differentiating $$\frac{x}{\sqrt(z^2+x^2)}$$ with the quotient rules gives $$\frac{\sqrt(z^2+x^2)\times 1 - x^2(z^2+x^2)^{-0.5}}{z^2+x^2}$$ and this is $$\frac{z^2+x^2 - x^2}{(z^2+x^2)^{3/2}}$$

i.e connected to the first term of the integration.

Similarly for the second term, but the quotient rule isn't required for that term.

Answer (score 1):

a $u$-sub also works. let $u=z^2+x^2$

Comment: u-sub works for the second integral because du = 2x dx, but it's extremely difficult to construct the first integral.

Comment: ah yes, didn't notice there was no $x$ on top in the first integral.  easiest way is a trig sub. let $x=z \tan\theta$ @BoHuang

Comment: The first integral problem could be used in Putnam competition, I guess @user256872

Answer (score 0):

a way to simplify it from the go. is to notice it is symmetric at the midpoint so there isn't going to be a component in the x direction. so you can actually ignore the second integral ( if you don't believe me, because it's symmetric the second integral is actually an odd function which is zero when evaluated at -a to a